# R horizontal box plot

Tags: plot, point, box

I am trying to plot an R horizontal box plot with the `mean` points.

```
boxplot(dados$q3, main="Is content and language learning equally promoted ?", col="dodgerblue1", ylim=c(1,5))
mean<-mean(dados$q3,na.rm=T)
points (mean,col="black",pch=22)
```

Problem is if I set the box plot to be vertical it works - the `mean` appears (points), but in horizontal it does not.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
points (mean,order(mean),col="black",pch=22)
```